# Field that properly contains the field of complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Problem**

Give an example of a field that properly contains the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$

**Attempt**

Let us consider the polynomial ring over the field of complex numbers ,i.e.,

$\mathbb{C}$[x]= {$c_nx^n+.......+c_o|c_i \in \mathbb{C}$}

Field of quotients of $\mathbb{C}$[x] is

$\mathbb{C}$(x)={$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x],g(x) \neq 0$}

I am not able to move from here.

Comment: Well, that's the example.  $\mathbb{C}$ appears as the constants. ($g=1$, $f$ a constant)

Comment: That example is good!  What more do you need?

Comment: I am not able to see how it contains $\ mathbb{ C}$ explicitly. I am taking g(x)  be 1 .

Comment: @Randall Thanks{}{}{}{}{}{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, take $2 + i \in \mathbb C$. Define the polynomials $f(x) = 2 + i, g(x) = 1$, and note that $f/g \equiv 2+i$ is contained in $\{f/g : f,g \in \mathbb C[x], g \not \equiv 0\}$. Now, you know how to show that $\mathbb C$ is contained in this field  : take $x \in \mathbb C$ instead of $2+i$, and the argument is exactly the same.

To show that containment is *proper*, note that $\frac 1x$ is a quotient of polynomials, which does not correspond to any complex number, because as we observed above, all polynomials corresponding to complex numbers are constants, but this one is not.

---

More precisely, given a non-trivial field $F$, the quotient ring of the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $F$, always contains $F$ strictly as an image of a homomorphism from $F$ to this field (injective, as field homomorphisms are always injective).

Answer (score 1):

That's the example that I would give. Note that if $z_0\in\mathbb C$, if you define $f(x)=z_0$ and $g(x)=1$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ belongs to your field. In other words, you can see $z_0$ as an element of $\mathbb{C}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks{}{}{}{}{}

Answer (score 1):

You find $\Bbb C$ by making $g(x)=1$ and all the terms in $f(x)\ 0$ except the constant term.  $c_0$ ranges over $\Bbb C$ and there is your copy.

Comment: Thanks{}{}{}{}{}